# Exibir dados de um array de objetos armazenados em memória

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Não consigo fazer um método que retorna as informações dos alunos cadastrados.

```
package menu;

import java.util.Scanner;

import modelo.Aluno;
import repositorio.RepositorioAluno;

public class AlunoMain {

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static RepositorioAluno repositorio = new RepositorioAluno();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        menu();

    }

    public static void cadastrarAluno() {

        Aluno aluno = new Aluno();

        System.out.println("Nome do aluno: ");
        aluno.setNome(s.next());
        System.out.println("Cpf: ");
        aluno.setCpf(s.next());
        System.out.println("Email: ");
        aluno.setEmail(s.next());
        System.out.println("Instituição de ensino: ");
        aluno.setInstituicao(s.next());

        if (repositorio.cadastrarAluno(aluno) == true) {
            System.out.println("Aluno cadastrado!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Falha no cadastro!");
        }

        System.out.println("9-Menu");
        int menu = s.nextInt();
        if (menu == 9) {
            menu();
        }

    }



    public static void menu() {
        boolean terminar = false;

        System.out.println(
                "1-Cadastrar aluno | 2- Remover Aluno | 3-Procurar Aluno | 4-Exibir alunos cadastrados | 0-Sair");
        int escolher = s.nextInt();

        do {

            switch (escolher) {
            case 1:
                cadastrarAluno();

            case 2:
                removerAluno();

            case 3:
                procurarAluno();

            case 4:
                exibirCadastrados();
            }

        } while (terminar);
    }
}
```

Aqui é o método que tá na classe `RepositorioAluno` que estou tentando fazer que funcione

```
public Aluno exibirCadastrados() {
        Aluno[] alunosCadastrados = new Aluno[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < listaAluno.length; i++) {
            if (listaAluno[i] != null) {
                alunosCadastrados[i] = listaAluno[i];
                System.out.println(alunosCadastrados);
            }
        }
        return alunosCadastrados[];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este método dize exibir os cadastrados, mas ele também copia, sei lá porque, os dados para outro *array* e o retorna, eu tiraria tudo isso porque não faz sentido. Mas pra passar exibir basta mandar exibir o elemento em vez de mandar exibir o *array*.

```
public Aluno[] exibirCadastrados() {
    Aluno[] alunosCadastrados = new Aluno[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < listaAluno.length; i++) {
        if (listaAluno[i] != null) {
            alunosCadastrados[i] = listaAluno[i];
            System.out.println(alunosCadastrados[i]);
        }
    }
    return alunosCadastrados;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/AccessElement.java).

Aí simplifica:

```
public void exibirCadastrados() { for (Aluno aluno : listaAluno) if (aluno != null) System.out.println(aluno); }
```

O código tem diversos outros problemas, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: Ficaria feliz caso me informasse os diversos problemas, assim eu tentaria melhorar posteriormente. Obrigado.